# Grails binding checkbox to integer field

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm working with legacy database, which I can't change. And they use short integers in postgreSQL DB instead of boolean.

How can I bind short or int field to checkbox? Is there any easy way?

I have tried overriding setters and getters but I get hibernate validation errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a `transient` property to your class:

```
 class SomeClass {

   int originalLegacy

   boolean isLegacy(){ 0 != originalLegacyInt }

   void setLegacy( boolean v ){ originalLegacyInt = v ? 1 : 0 }

   static transients = [ 'legacy' ]
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was looking for. It's quite elegant solution compared to what I had in mind. I'm new with grails and groovy so I didn't knew about transients

Comment: it's fine, if you need it only in a couple of places. otherwise you might want to add such properties via `MetaClass` everywhere